# Jquery Show Input Text Based On Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input

I facing problem with my jquery, on showing input text based on input value.
Here is the JS fiddle demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltapp/364/

When I try to input @hotmail, the input box will show. But when I want to type some text in the #hotm input box, it will hide again.

JS code :

```
$(window).load(function(){
var myString = '@hotmail';
$('#hotm').hide();

$("input").keyup(function () {
var value = $(this).val();
    if($(this).val().match(myString)) {
        $('#hotm').show();
    } else {
        $('#hotm').hide(); 
    }
});

});
```

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/Ltapp/367/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your selector `$("input")` affects both input elements. I have updated it to the `$("input:first")` selector instead. [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltapp/368/)

```
    $("input:first").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value.match(myString)) {
        $('#hotm').show();
    } else {
        $('#hotm').hide(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As many has said, you are binding the event on all the inputs I did a little change:

```
$(function(){
    var myString = /@hotmail/ig;
    $("#check").bind('keyup checkvalue', function() {
        $('#hotm')[myString.test(this.value) ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    }).trigger('checkvalue');
});
```

using regex if you are using `@HoTmAil` it will also hit on that, and also added a custom event `checkvalue` to see if `#hotm` should be visible on for example a postback on the form you might be using.

---

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/xjwvT/1/

Answer (score 0):

You're affecting all inputs. Either give each one a unique ID / Class or use the jQuery $(this) method.

See JSFiddle Here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltapp/366/

```
<input type="text" id="firstinput"/>
<p id="secondinput"><input type="text"/></p>


var myString = '@hotmail';
$('#secondinput').hide();

$("#firstinput").keyup(function () {
var value = $(this).val();
    if($(this).val().match(myString)) {
        $('#secondinput').show();
    } else {
        $('#secondinput').hide(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for your if part :

```
if($(this).val().match($(this).val().substr(0,strlen($(this).val())))
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because the new box also = "input"; if you give the hotmail textbox it's own id, it won't hide

```
<input id="hotmail" type="text"/>
```

and then

```
$("#hotmail").keyup(function () {...});
```