# Jquery Clear Text If Textbox Hidden

Tags: jquery

I continue in my last questions : [Jquery Show Input Text Based On Input Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683908/jquery-show-input-text-based-on-input-value/16684196?noredirect=1#16684196)

Now I want to improve that code, if input text hide, then clear the text history in textbox.
and here is the JS code :

```
$(window).load(function(){
var myString = '03540B071-BIXXXXXX';
$('#secondinput').hide();

$("#firstinput").keyup(function () {
var value = $(this).val();
    if($(this).val().match(myString)) {
        $('#secondinput').show();
    } else {
        $('#secondinput').hide(); 
    }
});

});
```

demo fiddle here :
http://jsfiddle.net/Ltapp/367/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this

```
$("#firstinput").keyup(function () {
var value = $(this).val();
    if($(this).val().match(myString)) {
        $('#secondinput').show();
    } else {
        $('#secondinput').hide();
        $('#secondinput input').val("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
var value = $(this).val();
if($(this).val().match(myString)) {
    $('#secondinput').show();
} else {
    $('#secondinput').hide(); 
    $('#secondinput').val("");  //Add this
}
});
```

Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltapp/369/)

Comment: and whose text history..??

Comment: Please try the demo in fiddle. If I input "@hotmail", the textbox will appear. Now I input text in that textbox (example : goal) then I clear text @hotmail. I input "@hotmail" again, the text goal still appear there

Comment: And I think my ans is also same as @Andrew Ngo,and I gave 17min back